# Using Camera and storing captured result in SDCard in android

Tags: android

I want to make application in which i want to use camera as after the image is captured, i want to store that image in SDCard and display that image in Screen too.

Can anybody help me ...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`** intent to launch Camera Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
```

Have a detailed example here: http://labs.makemachine.net/2010/03/simple-android-photo-capture/ , which i think suitable to your problem as to capture image , store it in sd-card and then display image in imageview too.

Enjoy!!!

Comment: @rakesh yeh glad about your reply

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke system camera use below method:

```
private void startCameraActivity() {
    File file = new File("/sdcard/test/test.jpg");
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
}
```

when the invoke finished, you will get the picture use onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("MakeMachine", "requestCode:"+requestCode + ",resultCode: " + resultCode);
    switch(requestCode){
        case ModifyUserActivity.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA:
            switch (resultCode) {
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    picFileName = null;
                    Log.i("MakeMachine", "User cancelled");
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:                
                    File file = new File("/sdcard/test/test.jpg");
                    if(file.exists()){
                        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                        options.inSampleSize = 4;
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picFileName, options);
                        imgTakePhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                        imgTakePhoto.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

}
```