# open an camera app by intent and save picture on the SD and imageView

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, imageview, sd-card

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using Camera and storing captured result in SDCard in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597867/using-camera-and-storing-captured-result-in-sdcard-in-android)

I want to get picture from camera app, save it on SD and set imageView.
I made a code below. saving and imageView sometimes works. but sometimes the picture is saved on SD and imageView doesn't work.

When imageView doesn't work, it seems that mOutUri become null in onActivityResult.

I have tried to save a mOutUri on SharedPreferences in clkbutton. I can see the uri in onActivityResult but imageView doesn't work. at this time, mOutUri is also null.

```
public void clkbutton(View v){
    Intent intent = new Intent();

    // open camera app
    intent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    // save data in SD card
    Date date = new Date();
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-kk-mm-ss");
    String newPicFile = df.format(date) + ".jpg";
    mNewPicFile = newPicFile;
    String outPath = "/sdcard/" + newPicFile;
    File outFile = new File(outPath);
    mOutUri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);

    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mOutUri);       
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAPTURE_IMAGE);
}


 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    imageView.setImageURI(mOutUri);    
 }
```

It's so weird that it sometimes errors and sometimes works.

Answer (score 0):

In onActivityResult before you setImageUri you should check if file exists. You can lose mOutUri content when app changes orientation, and it happend sometime when you open camera. You should implement in activity onSaveInstanceState where you store into preferences your uri and onRestoreInstanceState where you restore your uri.

Answer (score 0):

try the following code:

```
    static Uri capturedImageUri=null;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
     this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
     photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  (cal.getTimeInMillis()+".jpg"));
    if(!file.exists()){
    try {
    file.createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
       }else{
     file.delete();
     try {
   file.createNewFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
capturedImageUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, capturedImageUri);
startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_RESULT);
   }
});

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
      if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {  
    //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    //imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    try {
    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap( getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),  capturedImageUri);
     imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
     e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }  
   }
```

and also dont forget to add some permissions in android manifets file like:

```
 `note: add permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in manifest file.`
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have tried your code but it still sometimes doesn't work. What do you think the problem is??